# How to early exit useEffect hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level) it says that we should only call hooks at the top level of our components. Due to the API of useEffect, `return` is already reserved for the cleanup which made me wonder how I could early exit a useEffect hook to prevent deeply nesting my if statements.

```
// instead of
React.useEffect(() => {
  if (foo){
    // do something
  }
})

// I would rather write something like
React.useEffect(() => {
  if (!foo){
    // exit early and stop executing the rest of the useEffect hook
  }

  // do something
})
```

How can I achieve this? In my first example, things could quickly get messy with complex conditional logic especially considering that I can't be using `useEffect` inside a conditional statement.

Comment: Like mentioned just doing `return` like in any JS function will work.   But first it might be an idea to think about why you need the condition.  Sometimes it might be better to split the component up more.  For example, lets say we have a component called `MultiEdit`, and what we want to do is have a property called `editType`, this will render two different styles of controls, so it might need different `useEffect` semantics, rather than use `if (!style1) return` etc, you could just create 2 sub components, say called `EditStyle1` & `EditStyle2` etc. You can then conditionally render these.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you'd want to reverse your logic to check for `!condition` when checking for the condition is clearer. But in any case, `if...else if...else` is the right approach and it works fine. Don't forget to clean things up you can break things out into multiple `useEffect` hooks if needed.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

As with any function, it can be exited early with `return` keyword.

These two snippets are equivalent:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  if (foo){
    // do something
  }
})


React.useEffect(() => {
  if (!foo){
    return;
  }

  // do something
})
```

Comment: Oh so the cleanup will only be triggered if I return a function like `return () => /* cleanup */`?

Comment: That's correct. `return;`, `return undefined;` and no return at all are fully interchangeable in JS.

Comment: I am getting a `Unnecessary return statement  no-useless-return` error while trying to do the same

Comment: @VedantShah It's linter error. If linter rule prevents you from writing the code you need then disable it, per line or per project. It could be the opposite, depending on the style of code it enforces.

Comment: In a useEffect, you can use an early return but it doesnt feel like a good pratice.
If you want to use your unmount callback you have to break you early return logic.

Comment: @GuillaumeHuardHughes Yes, it would be the same for any other case in JS that involves branching. But here there's likely no need for cleanup logic when an effect is a no-op

Answer (score 5):

Please note that in React 18, you might get something like "destroy is not a function" error if you just "return" (return, or return false, or whatever) from useEffect.

That's because React 18 requires you to return a cleanup FUNCTION.

So an easy way out (not the best, I'd assume, but just as a **quick fix**), could be returning like that:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!goodToGo) {
    return () => {}
  }

  console.log("Doing stuff");
}, [goodToGo])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple solution is to create a function and do a return

```
 useEffect(() => {

        const fetchData = async () => {
           
           if (!foo) return

        }

        fetchData()

}, [])
```